# Fill with Quads in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a ring of quads between two Bezier curves in Geometry Nodes, like so:

[image]

What I've managed so far is a ring of triangles using the Fill Curve node:

[image]

... which is not ideal since the body that will result from this will be beveled, which doesn't work with the triangles.

I have two ideas how to go about this, but my geonodes-fu is not good enough yet ;-):

1. Do the triangles thing and try to figure out which of the edges to dissolve.
2. Do not use the Fill Curve node at all, but produce the ring of quads some other way.

The Bezier curves will have the same resolution, so in principle it should be pretty easy to turn each into a list of vertices and take corresponding pairs of two vertices from each list and turn those four into a quad, but I haven't figured out how to do that "foreach set of two vertices" thing yet.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Lapjoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to connect two shapes with the same number of points, point by point, so that you get a uniform mesh consisting of quads instead of triangles.

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

1. Convert the curves into a mesh (maybe use the node `Resample Curve` before, if you need a higher resolution of the mesh).
2. Capture the positions of the second mesh with `Capture Attribute`.
3. Extrude the mesh (here you can use arbitrary values).
4. Change the positions of the extruded edges (Selection *Top*) with `Set Position` and use the positions captured before.

The only important thing is that both shapes have the same number of points!

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LapJoint You're welcome!